# Ajax not showing the latest data in Rails , .js exact syntax

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am working on ROR app , One of my view is using drag and drop , so after user make drag and drop changes he clicks on button , which make changes to the database .The issue after pressing of button i need to refresh the page automatically but i am not able to do so.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
 $(function(){
  $('#btn').click(function() {
  var val="";
  $("table tr").each(function(){

  var value = $(this).text();
  var lines = value.split("\n"); 
  len=lines.length;

  if((len==5)||(len==9))
  val=val+lines[2]+" ";

});

jQuery.ajax({
 data: 'val=' + val,
 dataType: 'script',
 type: 'post',
 url: "/portfolio/update"
   });

 });
  });    
 </script>
```

My controller code:

```
def update
 # blah blah
 respond_to |format|
  format.html { redirect_to some_path }
  format.js # This will render default js template views/portfolio/update.js.erb
 end
```

end

What is the exact syntax to render the same page in update.js.erb ? I know its something windows.location.reload.I am novice in frontend.

Comment: `window.location.reload` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.location#Example_.232.3A_Force_reloading_the_current_page_from_the_server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use:

```
window.location.reload();
```

Comment: This is my update.js.erb  $('#div_to _update').html('new html code to update the view')  windows.location.reload();

Comment: it's: window.location (not plural - windows). also add a ; after the .html();